# Jmeter- Create HTTP request body using JSR223 Pre-processor

Tags: api, rest, automation, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to dynamically create HTTP Request body for a POST by using JSR223 Preprocessor. Below is the code that I tried. But it is not working. Request body is populating as empty. Can anyone help?

```
def arg= new HTTPArgument("", dataToBePosted, null, true);
arg.setAlwaysEncoded(false);
sampler.getArguments().addArgument(arg);
```

I also tried

```
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments();
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',dataToBePosted,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it might be the case you have a problem in your Groovy code, i.e. I fail to see `dataToBePosted` declared/initialized anywhere
2. Even if it is good it won't survive first iteration, I would suggest using [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html) class instance instead

Example code:

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', 'dataToBePosted', '', false)
body.setAlwaysEncoded(false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)
```

and demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: This solution is working fine for single request. I am using CSV config and iterating the list to process more than one requests with single sampler. There the request body is coming empty.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess why the "request body is coming empty" without seeing your code, CSV file structure, anticipated request body payload and so on, check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO documentation chapter. If you want to build a request from multiple lines of the CSV the approach with the [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) won't work as it reads next line from the file on each iteration of each user, you will need to read the file in Groovy.